# How to get the column that matches the search query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I'm trying to implement `pg_search` in my Rails application and wonder if there is a way to get the column that matches the search query? The index table content consists of all searchable column fields.

E.g.:

```
+-----------+----------+
| Firstname | Lastname |
+-----------+----------+
| John      | Doe      |
| Jane      | Doe      |
+-----------+----------+
```

will result in:

```
+----------+
| Content  |
+----------+
| John Doe |
| Jane Doe |
+----------+
```

And now I don't know if my search query matches the firstname or lastname. Are there any options to tell `pg_search` to add the column title to the content column too? Something like:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                 Content                  |
+------------------------------------------+
| {"firstname": "John", "Lastname": "Doe"} |
| {"firstname": "Jane", "Lastname": "Doe"} |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Or are there any search alternatives that fits my needs? `pg_search` works very well, particularly because of my multi-tenant/postgres-schema architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The nest solution is probably to generate tsvectors+query  on the fly for each column of matched rows..

Example:

```
select *,
(to_tsvector(p.first_name)@@ to_tsquery( 'joe:*' )) found_in_first_name,
(to_tsvector(p.last_name)@@ to_tsquery( 'joe:*' )) found_in_last_name
from people p 
where  p.fts @@ to_tsquery( 'joe:*' );
```

This example is likely the best solution, depending on how much data you're expecting to return in each result set

An alternative is to hack "weights" to get what you're wanting:

```
UPDATE people SET fts =
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(firstname,'')), 'A')    ||
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(lastname,'')), 'B');
```

SO, what we just did was give the firstname column a "weight" of "A" and the "lastname" column a "weight" of "B" in the tsvector. Keep in mind that "A","B","C" and "D" are the only valid weights,so if you need to do this with more than 4 columns, it won't work.

Your queries can query a specific weight if needed, and the weights are visible in the text representation of the tsvector, however they are NOT available when searching (IE, returning which weight the search terms were found in)

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand where to place the `tsvector` code  - OK, I don't understand the code itself, I should have a look at the documentation - but: does this even work with multiple search? If there are 40 results, do I have to execute the select query for each row, even if the models are the same? Wouldn't it be a performance killer? Alternative 2 wouldn't work for me since I'm using more than 4 columns. I think the best option would be storing JSON in the content table (and since Postgres 9.4 it could be done with JSONB).

Comment: What do you mean "multiple search"? My first example works with multiple terms if that's what you're asking.. as for your models, this code should be included in your models when a search is ran, it's an addition to the basic select statement that's already being ran, and it's not a separate select statement.